# How to convert matrix to image matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix, spatial

I mean, is there any function which can convert large 3d matrix (with good performance) to image-like one? Namely, I have a sample:

```
mat = matrix(c(c(3,5,6,7,8,4,4,6,5,6),
               c(3,4,5,7,6,4,5,4,6,6),
               c(9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9,9)), ncol = 3, byrow = F)
```

When I `plot` it's just simple 6:5 matrix. The point is to get this image as a matrix so that x-axis become 1st dimention, y-axis 2nd dimension and a value an attribute. So, as in the plot, where no value (here 9) this coordinate would be NA.

I've tried to convert using `raster`, `SpatialPoints`, `as.raster`, `as.Image`, however, there's always missing something for this functions.

**EDIT**

Found very straightforward solution:

```
xmax = max(mat[,1]); ymax = max(mat[,2])
xmin = min(mat[,1]); ymin = min(mat[,2])
dx = xmax - xmin + 1
dy = ymax - ymin + 1

mval = NULL
for (ix in (1:dx)) {  #ix=1
  for (iy in (1:dy)) {  #iy=2
    #stop()
    if (any(mat[,1] == (ix+xmin-1) & mat[,2] == (iy+ymin-1))) {
      mval = c(mval, mat[ix,][3])
    } else {
      mval = c(mval, NA)
    }
  }
}

mi = matrix(mval, nrow = dx, byrow = T)
rownames(mi) <- c(xmin:xmax)
colnames(mi) <- c(ymin:ymax)
```

I'm sure there's a better implementation somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
library(raster)
r <- rasterFromXYZ(mat)
```